# Good way to "keep" newline character in JSON?

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I'm building a Java Jersey 2 Rest API (crawler). The crawler retrieves text from articles and returns it in json. The API will be later used by other developers.

So my question is - how can i "keep" newline characters in a String in my json output?

Example of another service dealing with this problem (json output):

```
"text": "When Etsy bought Grand St. last April, . But that’s about to change. At the end of this month, Grand St. will stop processing orders and on October 1, listings on the site will become inactive. At that point, Grand St.’s site will just be a gallery of content and photos.\nThat’s because the Grand St. team has taken on a lot more projects at Etsy, so from a user experience and maintenance perspective, it made sense to move Grand St. away from commerce, Etsy Senior PR Manager Nicole Summer told TechCrunch.\n“We at Etsy and Grand St. have truly appreciated all the hard work from Grand St. makers, and we welcome them to learn more about joining the Etsy community,” Summer said. “The Grand St. team has become an integral part of the Etsy organization, working on innovative projects to help our sellers scale. We’re grateful to have them on board and excited to continue the work we’re doing to empower our sellers to achieve their creative business goals on their own terms.”\nFor background, Grand St. sells things like solar chargers, a smart light for nighttime bike rides and The Cash Cannon for making it rain. Before the acquisition, Grand St. had raised $1.3 million in seed funding from First Round Capital, David Tisch, Gary Vaynerchuk, betaworks, Collaborative Fund, MESA+, Quotidian Ventures, and Undercurrent.\nFeatured Image: Dennis Skley/Flickr UNDER A CC BY-ND 2.0 LICENSE",
```

You can see that they are using \n in their json.

Comment: I think '\n'(standard way) is nice way to pass newline in json from service and client understands it and break statement from there.

Comment: Thank you :) The problem is, that the JSON parsers (jackson) removes these characters from the string (\n). Any hints how to prevent this?

Comment: see my answer below, let me know if it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using Jackson and doing in way shown below (only pasted specific portion here).
For me things are working, change it as per your need.

```
@GET
@Path("/getLocale")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON} )
public Response getLocale(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(200);

    String str=null;
    byte[] bytes=null;

    String appLocation = SystemParameters.getInstance().getParameter("application.home.dir")+"/WEB-INF/lang/";

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(appLocation+"/en_US.json");

    try {
        bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //ERROR
    }

    str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    str = str.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
    str = str.replaceAll("\\t", "");
    str = str.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");

    return responseBuilder.entity(str).build();
}
```

JSON File:

```
"CERTIFICATE_STATUS_PASSWORD_INVALID":"Unable to read certificate with the given password.\nUpload the certificate with a valid password."
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try that later and come back to you.

Comment: This works - i just thought an interceptor could be a great way to handle that! What do you think?

Comment: They said keep newlines, but it looks like you're stripping them out?...